# WordPress API pagination returns only two pages.

Tags: wordpress

I have an events page with a calendar on the sidebar. Each time the user clicks on a date I load all the events from that date via an API endpoint that I created.
So far everything is good, but I have an issue with pagination.
If the user just entered to the events page pagination will work perfect, however when the user hits the calendar to load events via the API it ruins the pagination and always return the next_post_link as page number 2.
Just incase I also configured in settings that posts_per_page would be the same as custom query, but it doesn't help.

```
<?php

function get_events(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    global $post;
    $event_date = $request["event_date"];
    $paged = ($request["paged"]) ? $request["paged"] : 1;
    $date = '';

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'meta_key'       => 'event_date',
        'meta_value'     => $event_date,
        'meta_compare'   => '>=',
        'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
        'order'          => 'ASC'
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    ob_start();

    include(locate_template('events_template.php'));

    $events = ob_get_contents();
    ob_get_clean();
    return $events;
}
```

Events template:

```
<div class="posts-container">
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div>
            <?php
                //Here we group events by event_date and add the date at the top.
                $event_date =  get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event_date', true );
                if ( $event_date != $date )
                {
                    $event_date_formatted = date( 'l, F jS, Y', strtotime( $event_date ) );
                    echo "<p class='page-header'><strong>$event_date_formatted</strong></p>";
                    $date = $event_date;
                }


            ?>
            <div class="event ath-card">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event_location', true ) ?></p>
                <p><?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'event_details', true ) ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="loader text-center hidden">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
</div>

<div class="div pagination-container text-center">
    <?php
        //always returns page number 2.
        //I run the exact query in the page itself and it works fine
        next_posts_link( '<button class="ath-btn ath-btn-info">LOAD MORE</button>', $the_query->max_num_pages );
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I couldn't fix the problem in a normal fashion, but luckily the

```
 <?php $the_query->max_num_pages ?>
```

returned the correct total pages so I used it to manually set the next post link.

I added this:

```
if($paged < $the_query->max_num_pages)
{
    $next_page = $paged + 1;
}
else
{
    $next_page = null;
}
```

And this:

```
<?php if ( $next_page ) : ?>
    <a href="http://localhost:8888/water/wp-json/events/v1/events/page/<?php echo $next_page ?>/?event_date=<?php echo $request["event_date"] ?> ">
        <button class='ath-btn ath-btn-info'>LOAD MORE</button>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```